# How to kill process with the same name but ran in different directory?

Tags: kill, ps

in directory `a` I ran a Python process named `basic.py` and then I ran another Python process in directory `b` named `basic.py` too. And I want to kill the process ran in directory `b`, however when I used `ps -ef | grep basic.py`, I couldn't tell which one to kill?

```
$ ps -ef | grep basic
doom     38218     1 99 Jul15 ?        2-17:27:30 python3 basic.py
doom     39222     1 99 Jul15 ?        5-14:21:03 python3 basic.py
```

How can I get the directory and kill that process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this super user answer](https://superuser.com/a/103409/370509) by [akira](https://superuser.com/users/10674/akira)

```
% sudo ls -l /proc/PID/exe
```

eg:

```
% ps -auxwe | grep 24466
root     24466  0.0  0.0   1476   280 ?        S     2009   0:00 supervise sshd
% sudo ls -l /proc/24466/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  1 18:05 /proc/24466/exe -> /package/admin/daemontools-0.76/command/supervise
```